# Call Windows batch file from a Go program so that it opens in a new window

Tags: windows, batch-file, go, cmd

I have a batch file named cfw.bat which will accept 1 command-line parameter.

I need to invoke or open this batch file from my go program and not to run as a command within go (because command within Go is not considering window's commands).

This is my go code

```
    foundationUrl := foundations.GetFoundationApiUrl(foundationNumber)
    command := exec.Command("call","cfw.bat",foundationUrl)
    fmt.Print("Executing Command >>> ")
    fmt.Println(command.Args)
    bs,err :=command.CombinedOutput()
```

This is the error i get

```
Executing Command >>> [call cfw.bat https://api.sys-pcf.com]
Error exec: "call": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

Couldn't execute windows command.. If i directly execute using cfw.bat from go code, it won't work because the shell used by Go is only Linux / Unix supported

Please help on how to trigger the batch as a seperate window from my Go Program

Comment: `cmd /k call cfw.bat`, if memory serves.

Comment: It is not opening the batch file, rather executing within Go's shell

Comment: I'll take a stab at this syntax `cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/C", "C:\\scripts\\cfw.bat", foundationUrl)`

Comment: still executing in Go's shell

Comment: What happens if you chnage it to `cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/K", "Echo Hello")` If this doesn't work, it may be worth checking the actual content of the `%PATH%` variable.

Comment: it works fine.. but my batch-file has few commands that will not work in Go shell

Comment: And you definitely used the full path to `cfw.bat` complete with double backslashes? or maybe `cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/C", \`C:\scripts\cfw.bat\`, foundationUrl)`

Comment: yes.`command := exec.Command("CMD","/C","c:\\me\\fcf\\cfw.bat",foundationUrl)`

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want your batch script be run by a `cmd.exe` instance run in a *separate window?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my comments:

```bat
cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/C", "C:\\me\\fcf\\cfw.bat", foundationUrl)
```

*Where backslashes are doubled and you provide the full path to `cfw.bat`*

An alternative may be to use backticks instead:

```bat
cmd := exec.Command(`cmd.exe`, `/C`, `C:\me\fcf\cfw.bat`, foundationUrl)
```

If you just want to open the batch file in another cmd.exe instance then maybe this would do it:

```bat
cmd := exec.Command(`cmd.exe`, `/C`, `Start C:\me\fcf\cfw.bat`, foundationUrl)
```

Comment: still its executing within the same shell.. Not opening as a seperate batch file window or performing the said windows operations. This is because Go's shell is not the real window shell

Comment: `command :=exec.Command("CMD","/C","c:/me/fcf/cfw.bat",foundationUrl)`

Comment: I used this `command := exec.Command("CMD","/C",`c:\me\fcf\cfw.bat`,foundationUrl)` still same

Comment: Did you try the commands in my actual answer? and did you check the content of `%PATH%`?

Comment: It is executing the batch file but not in a separate window. Go is executing within its own shell and then not executing properly

Comment: @Arun, my answer is correct then, I have provided a solution to your inability to call a batch file. Any further issues, lie either in the batch file code or the go code, neither of which fall within the remit of your question!

Comment: Prepend [`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) to the command line suggested by @Compo.

Comment: @Compo : My question is on how to execute this from Go's shell. Precisely, i need to get off from Go's shell and execute the batch file. Trigger the batch file and it gets opened in a seperate window, not within Go shell

Comment: @Arun there's no such thing as a "Go shell", so we have a terminological issue.

Comment: when i execute the `start` command, it says `Error exec: "start": executable file not found in %PATH%`

Comment: `Executing Command >>> [cmd.exe start c:\me\fcf\cfw.bat https://api.sys-pcf.com]
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.`

Comment: @Arun exchange `start` and `cmd.exe` so that you get `start cmd.exe ...`

Comment: @Arun also don't forget to refer to a person whose comment you're replying to with `@person`—otherwise they won't get notified (I wasn't, for instance).